# Changing time zone of XTS object

Tags: r, xts

I have an data object with

```
index(x)
[6217] "2014-09-03 GMT" "2014-09-04 GMT" "2014-09-05 GMT" "2014-09-08 GMT" "2014-09-09 GMT" "2014-09-10 GMT" "2014-09-11 GMT"
[6224] "2014-09-12 GMT"
```

What can I do to change the objects time zone to "CDT"? Is there a function to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `indexTZ<-`

```
indexTZ(x) <- "America/Chicago"
```

Comment: is there a way to take out the time component? I have `"2014-09-11 19:00:00 CDT"` I just want `"2014-09-11 CDT"`

Comment: @user1234440: if you don't care about the time, then why do you care about the timezone?

Comment: im comparing two objects and I need to standardize them. the other object I am comparing to looks like `"2014-09-11 CDT"`.

Comment: @user1234440 If you really want to do that, here is one way. `gsub("\\s.*\\s", " ", x)`

Comment: or even `format(index(x), "%F %Z")` if converting to character is really desired.  I'm not clear on what the actual use case is here.

Comment: Why not just use `as.Date()`?

Comment: @drenerbas because dates don't have timezones and user1234440 asked for a string that includes "CDT"